# How to filter light through non transparent pixel in texture?

Tags: unity-game-engine

A transparent plane (`TP`) with a texture is positioned between a light and a plane (`P`).

`TP`'s texture holds different rectangle of colors representing bounding polygons of image on `P`. For instance `P` has an image of a car on it and on `TP` the car's contour (in a given color). The goal of those planes is to be able to click on `P`, check the corresponding pixel color on `TP` and then say "You clicked on a car" or whatever.

Now I want to highlight the car on the image. For the moment, I compute the centroid of each color (so of each object) in `TP` and point a spotlight in this direction. We can note that if a pixel is transparent, we consider that there is no interesting objects.

You can imagine that for complex shapes it won't be accurate at all. So I thought that maybe we could filter the light from that spotlight in function of the alpha channel of the pixel it goes through. So if the pixel is non transparent, the light goes through it and if the pixel on the texture is transparent, the light bounce on it or whatever.

Answer (score 0):

If raycasting with Layers is not an option, and you really want to do this using lights, consider the following:

Place all relevant objects in the "Transparent" Queue. These objects will be drawn back-to-front. That may help with non-transparent pixels.

"Zwrite Off" *may* help but I'm not sure if that's what you want.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am not I understood your suggestion, let me rephrase my question. I have an invisible 2d texture containing convex shapes, the rest of the texture contains transparent pixels. I want to be able to block the light passing through transparent pixels. The problem is that my texture is not visible in the scene.

Comment: then put it in the geometry queue (select material and set queue in shader settings)